# Why selenium not detecting sign in prompt as alert?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill out a sign in prompt using selenium, however it is not detecting it as an alert or prompt.

[image]

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https:://examplewebpage")
obj = driver.switch_to.alert
obj.send_keys("Hello World!")
sleep(2)
obj.accept()
```

**Error trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\210320\PycharmProjects\Daymap Intergration\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    obj = driver.switch_to.alert
  File "C:\Users\210320\PycharmProjects\Daymap Intergration\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 55, in alert
    alert.text
  File "C:\Users\210320\PycharmProjects\Daymap Intergration\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\alert.py", line 67, in text
    return self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_GET_ALERT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "C:\Users\210320\PycharmProjects\Daymap Intergration\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\210320\PycharmProjects\Daymap Intergration\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message:
```

Comment: Can you share test creds if you have any ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `driver.get()` to the following instead of the `switch_to.alert` method -

```
driver.get("https://username:password@url")
```

This should ideally get you to authenticate immediately on navigating to the webpage with the immediate sign-in prompt.

> **NOTE:** Please be careful of adding the username and the password directly to the selenium script, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: So if my url was `https://example.com` would I do `https://example.com:password@url`?

Comment: no, as i mentioned above - `https://username:password@example.com`, so if your username was 'admin' and password was 'password@123' then - `https://admin:password@123@example.com`

Comment: Thanks, but I just realised, my original url redirects to a temporary url before displaying prompt, how may I use it then, cause it does not work. The url I am using is: `https://daymap.gihs.sa.edu.au/daymap`

Comment: @AkshaySehgal : It could be a modal pop up windows also, without seeing the webpage or at least HTML DOM, it's a guess whatever you've written above

Comment: @cruisepandey the webpage is `https://daymap.gihs.sa.edu.au/daymap`

Comment: Do we have testing creds to check from my end ?

Comment: @cruisepandey can you check from your end, cause my computer is running quite slow.

Comment: I need credentials to check this one out !